# How to set modal popup text editor to normal input box when dynamically add rows using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the dynamic data table, its all working perfectly but im facing small problem that is, **First row** is working properly and it is stable, the **Second row** **"NARRATION"** column, is only the problem.

That means Second row narration column having input popup text editor, thats fine its working, now i click **ADD NEW** button another row will come and click narrate column its again show the popup text editor.. i dont want like that..

> I want change the input modal text editor to normal input box. thats appear on dynamically added rows when i click add new button.
>
> Want 1st two rows is should want popup text editor, and dynamic added rows only wants to be input boxes..

**[Full Code FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/m9wdfcra/)**

```js
/* TABLE JS */

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add_row").on("click", function() {
    // Dynamic Rows Code

    // Get max row id and set new id
    var newid = 0;
    $.each($("#tab_logic tr"), function() {
      if (parseInt($(this).data("id")) > newid) {
        newid = parseInt($(this).data("id"));
      }
    });
    newid++;

    var tr = $("<tr></tr>", {
      id: "addr" + newid,
      "data-id": newid
    });

    // loop through each td and create new elements with name of newid
    $.each($("#tab_logic tbody tr:nth(1) td"), function() {
      var td;
      var cur_td = $(this);

      var children = cur_td.children();

      // add new td and element if it has a nane
      if ($(this).data("name") !== undefined) {
        td = $("<td></td>", {
          "data-name": $(cur_td).data("name")
        });

        var c = $(cur_td).find($(children[0]).prop('tagName')).clone().val("");
        c.attr("name", $(cur_td).data("name") + newid);
        c.appendTo($(td));
        td.appendTo($(tr));
      } else {
        td = $("<td></td>", {
          'text': $('#tab_logic tr').length
        }).appendTo($(tr));
      }
    });

    // add the new row
    $(tr).appendTo($('#tab_logic'));

    $(tr).find("td button.row-remove").on("click", function() {
      $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
  });

  // Sortable Code
  var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr) {
    var $originals = tr.children();
    var $helper = tr.clone();

    $helper.children().each(function(index) {
      $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
    });

    return $helper;
  };

  $(".table-sortable tbody").sortable({
    helper: fixHelperModified
  }).disableSelection();
  $(".table-sortable thead").disableSelection();
  $("#add_row").trigger("click");
});

/* POPUP JS */
$('.cashmodal_btn').on('click', function() {
  let val = $('.myInput').val();
  $('#pay_narrat').val(val);
});

$('.cashmodal_btn').on('click', function() {
  let val = $('.acnarrate').val();
  $('#acc_narrat').val(val);
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- table -->

<a id="add_row" class="btn btn-primary float-right adRow">Add New</a>
<div class="col-md-12 table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sortable" id="tab_logic">
    <thead style="background-color: #680779;
                                                        color: #fff;">
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center">
          Account Code
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
          A/c Name*
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
          Narration*
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
          Debit*
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
          Credit
        </th>
        <th class="text-center" style="border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;">
          Action
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="fst_row">
        <td>
          <input type="number" id="payacc_code" placeholder='Enter A/c code' class="form-control" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <select class="form-control" id="payacc">
            <option value="">Select TDS A/c name</option>
            <option value="1">JOE</option>
            <option value="2">JOE 2</option>
            <option value="3">JOE 3</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pay_narrat" placeholder="Enter your here" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#narratModal" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" id="paydeb" value="100" placeholder='Debit Amount' data-action="sumDebit" class="form-control" readonly />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" id="paycredit" placeholder='Credit Amount' class="form-control" readonly />
        </td>

        <td>
          <button class='btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove row-remove removeBtn' style="cursor: not-allowed" disabled><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id='addr0' class="hidden">
        <td data-name="cashCode">
          <input type="text" id="cashacc_code" name='cashacc_code' placeholder='Enter A/c Code' class="form-control" />
        </td>
        <td data-name="sel">
          <select class="form-control" name="cashacc_sel" id="cashacc_sel">
            <option value="">Select A/c name</option>
            <option value="1">Plumz</option>
            <option value="2">Plumz 2</option>
            <option value="3">Plumz 3</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td data-name="narrate">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="acc_narrat" placeholder="Enter your here" name="acc_narrat" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#accnarratModal" />
        </td>
        <td data-name="dbt">
          <input type="number" id="cashdeb" name='cashdeb' placeholder='Debit Amount' data-action="sumDebit" class="form-control" />
        </td>
        <td data-name="crdit">
          <input type="number" id="cashcredit" name='cashcredit' placeholder='Credit Amount' class="form-control" readonly />
        </td>

        <td data-name="del">
          <button name="del0" class='btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove row-remove removeBtn'><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>


<!-- narration text popup modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="narratModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="narratModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close cash-dismiss" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title modal_head" id="narratModalLabel">Narration</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <label class="modal_note">Note: Only alphabets A-Z a-z number 0-9 and characters % & [] () - _ . , are allowed in text</label>
        <input class="myInput form-control form-control-sm" style="height: 7em;" placeholder="Enter Here" />
        <span class="modal_valid">0/200 Characterts entered</span>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer narr_footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary cashmodal_btn" id="narrat_ok" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="accnarratModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="accnarratModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close cash-dismiss" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title modal_head" id="accnarratModalLabel">Narration</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <label class="modal_note">Note: Only alphabets A-Z a-z number 0-9 and characters % & [] () - _ . , are allowed in text</label>

        <textarea class="acnarrate form-control form-control-sm" style="height: 7em;" placeholder="Enter Here"></textarea>
        <span class="modal_valid">0/200 Characterts entered</span>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer narr_footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary cashmodal_btn" id="accnarrat_ok" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[Full code FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/m9wdfcra/)**

> I dont know my question is understandable or not..

Comment: When you are dealing with dynamic field, you have to execute `$(document)` query,instead of putting your events inside the ready function, try changing your click event to document click event, eg: `$(document).on('click', '#ID', function(){...})`. This should work fine!

Comment: @Joe, make sure you mark the answer which helped you to solve your issue as answered. It may help the future visitors as well as you can avoid the question listing under unanswered questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I understand your problem I updated your fiddle .

you just need to remove **data-toggle & data-target** property from newly created row. because you are cloning so each function with elements are cloning.

```
$("#"+trId +" #acc_narrat").removeAttr("data-target")
$("#"+trId +" #acc_narrat").removeAttr("data-toggle")
```

Here is working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/py0woeqx/5/)

Answer (score 2):

I got your problem. Check this code:

Update JS:

```
/* TABLE JS */

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add_row").on("click", function() {
    // Dynamic Rows Code

    // Get max row id and set new id
    var newid = 0;
    $.each($("#tab_logic tr"), function() {
      if (parseInt($(this).data("id")) > newid) {
        newid = parseInt($(this).data("id"));
      }
    });
    newid++;

    var tr = $("<tr></tr>", {
      id: "addr" + newid,
      "data-id": newid
    });

    // loop through each td and create new elements with name of newid
    $.each($("#tab_logic tbody tr:nth(1) td"), function() {
      var td;
      var cur_td = $(this);

      var children = cur_td.children();

      // add new td and element if it has a nane
      if ($(this).data("name") !== undefined) {
        td = $("<td></td>", {
          "data-name": $(cur_td).data("name")
        });

        var c = $(cur_td).find($(children[0]).prop('tagName')).clone().val("");
        c.attr("name", $(cur_td).data("name") + newid);
        c.appendTo($(td));
        td.appendTo($(tr));
      } else {
        td = $("<td></td>", {
          'text': $('#tab_logic tr').length
        }).appendTo($(tr));
      }
    });

    // add the new row
    $(tr).appendTo($('#tab_logic'));

    $(tr).find("td button.row-remove").on("click", function() {
      $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
  });

  // Sortable Code
  var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr) {
    var $originals = tr.children();
    var $helper = tr.clone();

    $helper.children().each(function(index) {
      $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
    });

    return $helper;
  };

  $(".table-sortable tbody").sortable({
    helper: fixHelperModified
  }).disableSelection();
  $(".table-sortable thead").disableSelection();
  $("#add_row").trigger("click");
});

/* POPUP JS */
$('.cashmodal_btn').on('click', function() {
  let val = $('.myInput').val();
  $('#pay_narrat').val(val);
});

$('.cashmodal_btn').on('click', function() {
  let val = $('.acnarrate').val();
  $(".acnarrate").val("");
  $('.active').val(val);
  $(".active").removeClass("active");
})

$(document).on('click',"input#acc_narrat", function() {
  $(".active").removeClass("active");
  $(".acnarrate").val( $(this).val() );
  $(this).addClass("active");
})
```

Comment: Welcome Dear Joe

Answer (score 1):

You are cloning row and changing ids but you need to remove `data-target="#narratModal"` from the input box so that modal will not be shown.
Just find the input box and remove `data-target="#narratModal"` attribute, see below code

```js
/* TABLE JS */

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add_row").on("click", function() {
    // Dynamic Rows Code

    // Get max row id and set new id
    var newid = 0;
    $.each($("#tab_logic tr"), function() {
      if (parseInt($(this).data("id")) > newid) {
        newid = parseInt($(this).data("id"));
      }
    });
    newid++;

    var tr = $("<tr></tr>", {
      id: "addr" + newid,
      "data-id": newid
    });

    // loop through each td and create new elements with name of newid
    $.each($("#tab_logic tbody tr:nth(1) td"), function() {
      var td;
      var cur_td = $(this);

      var children = cur_td.children();

      // add new td and element if it has a nane
      if ($(this).data("name") !== undefined) {
        td = $("<td></td>", {
          "data-name": $(cur_td).data("name")
        });

        var c = $(cur_td).find($(children[0]).prop('tagName')).clone().val("");
        c.attr("name", $(cur_td).data("name") + newid);
        c.appendTo($(td));
        td.appendTo($(tr));
      } else {
        td = $("<td></td>", {
          'text': $('#tab_logic tr').length
        }).appendTo($(tr));
      }
    });

    // add the new row
    $(tr).appendTo($('#tab_logic'));

    $(tr).find("td button.row-remove").on("click", function() {
      $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
    // remove data-target so that popup will not be shown
     $(tr).find('input[name^=narrat]').removeAttr('data-target');
  });

  // Sortable Code
  var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr) {
    var $originals = tr.children();
    var $helper = tr.clone();

    $helper.children().each(function(index) {
      $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
    });

    return $helper;
  };

  $(".table-sortable tbody").sortable({
    helper: fixHelperModified
  }).disableSelection();
  $(".table-sortable thead").disableSelection();
  $("#add_row").trigger("click");
});

/* POPUP JS */
$('.cashmodal_btn').on('click', function() {
  let val = $('.myInput').val();
  $('#pay_narrat').val(val);
});

$('.cashmodal_btn').on('click', function() {
  let val = $('.acnarrate').val();
  $('#acc_narrat').val(val);
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- table -->

<a id="add_row" class="btn btn-primary float-right adRow">Add New</a>
<div class="col-md-12 table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sortable" id="tab_logic">
    <thead style="background-color: #680779;
                                                        color: #fff;">
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center">
          Account Code
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
          A/c Name*
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
          Narration*
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
          Debit*
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
          Credit
        </th>
        <th class="text-center" style="border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;">
          Action
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="fst_row">
        <td>
          <input type="number" id="payacc_code" placeholder='Enter A/c code' class="form-control" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <select class="form-control" id="payacc">
            <option value="">Select TDS A/c name</option>
            <option value="1">JOE</option>
            <option value="2">JOE 2</option>
            <option value="3">JOE 3</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pay_narrat" placeholder="Enter your here" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#narratModal" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" id="paydeb" value="100" placeholder='Debit Amount' data-action="sumDebit" class="form-control" readonly />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" id="paycredit" placeholder='Credit Amount' class="form-control" readonly />
        </td>

        <td>
          <button class='btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove row-remove removeBtn' style="cursor: not-allowed" disabled><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id='addr0' class="hidden">
        <td data-name="cashCode">
          <input type="text" id="cashacc_code" name='cashacc_code' placeholder='Enter A/c Code' class="form-control" />
        </td>
        <td data-name="sel">
          <select class="form-control" name="cashacc_sel" id="cashacc_sel">
            <option value="">Select A/c name</option>
            <option value="1">Plumz</option>
            <option value="2">Plumz 2</option>
            <option value="3">Plumz 3</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td data-name="narrate">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="acc_narrat" placeholder="Enter your here" name="acc_narrat" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#accnarratModal" />
        </td>
        <td data-name="dbt">
          <input type="number" id="cashdeb" name='cashdeb' placeholder='Debit Amount' data-action="sumDebit" class="form-control" />
        </td>
        <td data-name="crdit">
          <input type="number" id="cashcredit" name='cashcredit' placeholder='Credit Amount' class="form-control" readonly />
        </td>

        <td data-name="del">
          <button name="del0" class='btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove row-remove removeBtn'><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>


<!-- narration text popup modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="narratModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="narratModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close cash-dismiss" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title modal_head" id="narratModalLabel">Narration</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <label class="modal_note">Note: Only alphabets A-Z a-z number 0-9 and characters % & [] () - _ . , are allowed in text</label>
        <input class="myInput form-control form-control-sm" style="height: 7em;" placeholder="Enter Here" />
        <span class="modal_valid">0/200 Characterts entered</span>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer narr_footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary cashmodal_btn" id="narrat_ok" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="accnarratModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="accnarratModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close cash-dismiss" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title modal_head" id="accnarratModalLabel">Narration</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <label class="modal_note">Note: Only alphabets A-Z a-z number 0-9 and characters % & [] () - _ . , are allowed in text</label>

        <textarea class="acnarrate form-control form-control-sm" style="height: 7em;" placeholder="Enter Here"></textarea>
        <span class="modal_valid">0/200 Characterts entered</span>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer narr_footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary cashmodal_btn" id="accnarrat_ok" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to properly clone your `td`s and remove the `data-target` property from the `input` field.

Here is the update I made to your element loop.

```
// loop through each td and create new elements with name of newid
$.each($("#tab_logic tbody tr:nth(1) td"), function() {
  var td;
  var cur_td = $(this).clone();  // <-- clone the td

  var children = cur_td.children();
  $(cur_td).find('#acc_narrat').removeAttr('data-toggle'); // <--- remove the attribute

  // add new td and element if it has a nane
  if ($(this).data("name") !== undefined) {
    td = $("<td></td>", {
      "data-name": $(cur_td).data("name")
    });

    var c = $(cur_td).find($(children[0]).prop('tagName')).clone().val("");
    c.attr("name", $(cur_td).data("name") + newid);
    c.appendTo($(td));
    td.appendTo($(tr));
  } else {
    td = $("<td></td>", {
      'text': $('#tab_logic tr').length
    }).appendTo($(tr));
  }
});
```

In short, You have to clone `var cur_td = $(this).clone();` the columns in order to loose the reference to your existing element.
And remove the relation to the modal from the element. `$(cur_td).find('#acc_narrat').removeAttr('data-toggle');`

I've updated your [fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/qkc24z6n/)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `attribute data-toggle` from `TD` before appending to `$('#tab_logic')`

```js
/* TABLE JS */

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add_row").on("click", function() {
    // Dynamic Rows Code

    // Get max row id and set new id
    var newid = 0;
    $.each($("#tab_logic tr"), function() {
      if (parseInt($(this).data("id")) > newid) {
        newid = parseInt($(this).data("id"));
      }
    });
    newid++;

    var tr = $("<tr></tr>", {
      id: "addr" + newid,
      "data-id": newid
    });

    // loop through each td and create new elements with name of newid
    $.each($("#tab_logic tbody tr:nth(1) td"), function() {
      var td;
      var cur_td = $(this);

      var children = cur_td.children();

      // add new td and element if it has a nane
      if ($(this).data("name") !== undefined) {
        td = $("<td></td>", {
          "data-name": $(cur_td).data("name")
        });

        var c = $(cur_td).find($(children[0]).prop('tagName')).clone().val("");
        c.attr("name", $(cur_td).data("name") + newid);
        c.appendTo($(td));
        td.appendTo($(tr));
      } else {
        td = $("<td></td>", {
          'text': $('#tab_logic tr').length
        }).appendTo($(tr));
      }
    });
    
    $(tr).find('#acc_narrat').removeAttr('data-toggle');

    // add the new row
    $(tr).appendTo($('#tab_logic'));

    $(tr).find("td button.row-remove").on("click", function() {
      $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
  });

  // Sortable Code
  var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr) {
    var $originals = tr.children();
    var $helper = tr.clone();

    $helper.children().each(function(index) {
      $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
    });

    return $helper;
  };

  $(".table-sortable tbody").sortable({
    helper: fixHelperModified
  }).disableSelection();
  $(".table-sortable thead").disableSelection();
  $("#add_row").trigger("click");
});

/* POPUP JS */
$('.cashmodal_btn').on('click', function() {
  let val = $('.myInput').val();
  $('#pay_narrat').val(val);
});

$('.cashmodal_btn').on('click', function() {
  let val = $('.acnarrate').val();
  $('#acc_narrat').val(val);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- table -->

<a id="add_row" class="btn btn-primary float-right adRow">Add New</a>
<div class="col-md-12 table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sortable" id="tab_logic">
    <thead style="background-color: #680779;
                                                        color: #fff;">
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center">
          Account Code
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
          A/c Name*
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
          Narration*
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
          Debit*
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
          Credit
        </th>
        <th class="text-center" style="border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;">
          Action
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="fst_row">
        <td>
          <input type="number" id="payacc_code" placeholder='Enter A/c code' class="form-control" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <select class="form-control" id="payacc">
            <option value="">Select TDS A/c name</option>
            <option value="1">JOE</option>
            <option value="2">JOE 2</option>
            <option value="3">JOE 3</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pay_narrat" placeholder="Enter your here" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#narratModal" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" id="paydeb" value="100" placeholder='Debit Amount' data-action="sumDebit" class="form-control" readonly />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" id="paycredit" placeholder='Credit Amount' class="form-control" readonly />
        </td>

        <td>
          <button class='btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove row-remove removeBtn' style="cursor: not-allowed" disabled><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id='addr0' class="hidden">
        <td data-name="cashCode">
          <input type="text" id="cashacc_code" name='cashacc_code' placeholder='Enter A/c Code' class="form-control" />
        </td>
        <td data-name="sel">
          <select class="form-control" name="cashacc_sel" id="cashacc_sel">
            <option value="">Select A/c name</option>
            <option value="1">Plumz</option>
            <option value="2">Plumz 2</option>
            <option value="3">Plumz 3</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td data-name="narrate">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="acc_narrat" placeholder="Enter your here" name="acc_narrat" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#accnarratModal" />
        </td>
        <td data-name="dbt">
          <input type="number" id="cashdeb" name='cashdeb' placeholder='Debit Amount' data-action="sumDebit" class="form-control" />
        </td>
        <td data-name="crdit">
          <input type="number" id="cashcredit" name='cashcredit' placeholder='Credit Amount' class="form-control" readonly />
        </td>

        <td data-name="del">
          <button name="del0" class='btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove row-remove removeBtn'><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>


<!-- narration text popup modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="narratModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="narratModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close cash-dismiss" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title modal_head" id="narratModalLabel">Narration</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <label class="modal_note">Note: Only alphabets A-Z a-z number 0-9 and characters % & [] () - _ . , are allowed in text</label>
        <input class="myInput form-control form-control-sm" style="height: 7em;" placeholder="Enter Here" />
        <span class="modal_valid">0/200 Characterts entered</span>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer narr_footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary cashmodal_btn" id="narrat_ok" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="accnarratModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="accnarratModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close cash-dismiss" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title modal_head" id="accnarratModalLabel">Narration</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <label class="modal_note">Note: Only alphabets A-Z a-z number 0-9 and characters % & [] () - _ . , are allowed in text</label>

        <textarea class="acnarrate form-control form-control-sm" style="height: 7em;" placeholder="Enter Here"></textarea>
        <span class="modal_valid">0/200 Characterts entered</span>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer narr_footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary cashmodal_btn" id="accnarrat_ok" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```